# BIOS to UEFI no backup restore possible?

Tags: windows, gpt, uefi, mbr, backup

We have a DELL R510 server with Windows SBS 2011 (Data, Exchange, ...), we running out of space on the server. We currently have this configuration:

- 2x 300GB SAS in RAID 1
- 2x 2TB SATA in RAID 1

We want to add 4x 4TB SAS in RAID 10. To be able to read the new hard drive we need to change the server boot option from BIOS to UEFI.

My question is: Can I backup the server (bare metal with windows backup), change from BIOS to UEFI and restore the backup, without reinstalling ? If not, how can I proceed (convert MBR to GPT) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer:

> No. You cannot restore BIOS firmware backup on to a fresh install on
>   UEFI. GPT/MBR is not the issue. It's a different firmware. Among other
>   things, you will get "inaccessible boot device" blue screen. You will
>   need to backup, do a fresh install on UEFI, install and configure all
>   apps, and restore data.

Comment: where does this answer comes from? some online document?

Comment: I get the answer from Microsoft Forum: [bios-to-uefi-no-backup-restore-possible] (http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/899dd551-e238-47e6-ba9a-74c107288e31/bios-to-uefi-no-backup-restore-possible?forum=windowsbackup)

Answer (score 0):

Most modern operating systems support BIOS and UEFI in single installation

but you should note that many proprietary softwares relay on NTFS or disk signature as part of their license management mechanism
 so you should do a block level backup&restore or manually restore previous NTFS signature and for disk signature(if any of your applications using it) there is not simple solution ...

Answer (score -1):

Microsoft haven't really accommodated this and I don't think they are upto date with the current bios changes. This should be seem-less.